Where to put S wires on Honeywell RTH9585WF thermostat
My old Z-Wave Honeywell thermostat has 2 S wires. I believe the S wires are for outside temperature sensing. Where do I put the two s wires on the new rth9585wf smartcolor thermostat? There are no ports present to put these s wires into.

Have you traced those wires to verify where they lead? (i.e. to a sensor on the outside of the house vs. somewhere else)  Your theory sounds about right but probably best to make sure before recommending you just nut them off and ignore outdoor temp sensing

The Support page for that thermostat indicates the outdoor temperature comes from the zip code you configure and uses Accuweather. It doesn't use a local temperature sensor.

Thermostat Functions:
...
Outdoor Weather / Forecast: Display current outdoor weather (based on zip code related to accuweather) and display 5-day forecast

